# Unit testing code that calls member function template

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I have a class like this in my code

```
class C
{
public:
    ...
    template <typename T>
    void f(const T& t)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
};
```

A reference to a `C` instance is shared to many other classes that all call `f`. The problem is that `C` is difficult to use in unit tests and especially it's difficult to verify the argument `f` was called with. This makes all other code using `C` difficult to test.

Are there any good techniques to "mock" `C` and `f` in unit tests?

Comment: You might want to *"templatize"* your other class to provide `C` in productuction and some `TestC` in UnitTest.

Comment: Have you looked at Mockitopp? It only really supports pure abstract class interfaces. https://github.com/tpounds/mockitopp